# Write to file after match in Kotlin

Tags: sed, kotlin

New to Kotlin, I'd like to insert a line in the file after a specific match in the file.  I know how to do this with sed like the following:

```
sed "/some line in file/a some text I'd like to add after line" file
```

But I'd like to understand how I'd go about this in Kotlin.  So far I've got got as far as the printWriter interface, but I don't see anything that clearly implies an offset or regex parameter.

So far I've got:

```
File("file.txt").printWriter(...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GNU 'sed' does not insert/remove/update lines in files, it transforms an input stream and provides options for sending the output stream to `stdout`, to a file, or even to a temporary file which then overwrites the original file after the transformation is complete (this is the `--in-place` option).

Here is some code that should get you started but note that there are lots of ways to buffer and read/write files, streams, etc.

```
val file = File("file.txt")
val tempFile = createTempFile()
val regex = Regex("""some line in file""")
tempFile.printWriter().use { writer ->
    file.forEachLine { line ->
        writer.println(when {
            regex.matches(line) -> "a some text I'd like to add after line"
            else -> line
        })
    }
}
check(file.delete() && tempFile.renameTo(file)) { "failed to replace file" }
```

See also [sed, a stream editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for more details on how it transforms text streams.

Comment: Ah! I suspected it might be something of this nature.  Thanks!