# Read line and append something at the end

Tags: kotlin

I'm new in kotlin. I'm trying to read file line by line and add something at the end to each of them.

My file before reading:

```
abcd;abcd;abcd;
bcda;bcda;bcda;
dacb;dacb;dacb;
```

My file after reading and appending:

```
abcd;abcd;abcd;smth1
bcda;bcda;bcda;smth2
dacb;dacb;dacb;smth3
```

I have code for reading file line by line but could you tell me how to add string to each of them?

```
val pathToFile = "abc.txt"
val scan = Scanner(File(pathToFile))
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    val line = scan.nextLine()
    var lista = ArrayList<String>()
    lista = line.split(";") as ArrayList<String>
    println(lista.get(0) + " and " + lista.get(1) + " and " + lista.get(2))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Januson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2392960/januson) has the right [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41675005/3255152). Here is some Kotlin code to do the job:

```
inline fun File.mapLines(crossinline transform: (line: String) -> String) {
    val tempFile = createTempFile(prefix = "transform", suffix = ".txt")
    tempFile.printWriter().use { writer ->
        this.forEachLine { line -> writer.println(transform(line)) }
    }
    check(this.delete() && tempFile.renameTo(this)) { "failed to replace file" }
}
```

Example usage:

```
val pathToFile = "abc.txt"
var index = 0
File(pathToFile).mapLines { line -> "${line}smth${++index}" }
```

If you are using Java 1.7+ then you can use `Files.move` instead of `delete`/`renameTo`:

```
Files.move(tempFile.toPath(), this.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

See also [Write to file after match in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41278921/3255152).

Answer (score 1):

You can't read and write to the same file unless you are using [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Instead you should do the following:

- Read line from your input file.
- Do the modification you want (append to the end of the line, print line).
- Write modified line to the output file.
- After reading/writing all the data close both files.
- Delete input file. Rename output file to the input file name.